# Azure AD, Synchronisation services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

After deleting some users from my Azure AD (via the Windows Azure Active Directory-module for Windows PowerShell)

I have a problem that those users won't re-synchronise with the Azure AD. 
Any new users that I add in the on-premises Active Directoy will be added to the Azure AD without any problems.
But any users that already were in the Azure AD before the delete command, won't re-import.

I can't recover the users in Azure AD, because I've already deleted the recycling bin.

Does someone know any solution, that may work?

Comment: Hi Christophe, Can you look in the Sync logs and provide us with the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contact with the support of Office365.

The solution was quite easy:

1) The users entry was still present in metaverse and hence they were not able to get synced

2) I deleted the connectors and connector space of AD and WAAD connector.

3) Once that was done, I ran the configuration wizard again, however I made sure I didn't ran the sync cycle after completion of configuration wizard

4) Once OU filtering was done , I ran the sync cycle